# Why can't I generate my own JWT to fake authentication?

Tags: jwt

[JWT tokens](https://jwt.io/) are self-contained. If a valid JWT token contains username and the token is valid, then the endpoint will think user is authenticated.

The token can be decoded and all fields seen.

What if I generate token on my side and fill it with data I saw, how will the system distinguish my token from it's own ones?

Comment: I've edited your question and title a bit for clarity. Feel free to roll back my changes or edit it further if you don't like my changes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple: A JWT must be properly signed or encrypted with the private key of the authenticating server.

If you don't have that private key then you would have to sign/encrypt with your own private key. You can do that, and thus generate a valid JWT, but the application you send it to will easily be able to tell it was signed with the wrong key, and thus will refuse to accept it (assuming that there aren't mistakes made during the JWT validation process).

Comment: As someone who's written a toy OAuth Relying Party framework, I will say that the RP does have Issuer keys **that it should check the JWT signatures against**. *e.g.*, for Google, these are got by: https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration → `jwks_uri` field → https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs

Answer (score 3):

You can generate your own JWT token like you state, but it will not be accepted by the backend.

To see, why, take this example token:

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c
```

If you look closely, you see 2 times a '.' (dot).

Everything before the first dot is the header, and decodes in this example as:

```
{
  "alg": "HS256",
  "typ": "JWT"
}
```

The part between the first and second dot is the payload which holds your claims and decodes in this example as:

```
{
  "sub": "1234567890",
  "name": "John Doe",
  "iat": 1516239022
}
```

Then finally, everything after the second dot is the verification signature.
So this part:

```
SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c
```

This signature is computed based on the information in the header and the payload. Furthermore, the encryption algorithm used is provided in the header: `HMAC SHA256` in this example.

To run this encryption algorithm on the header and payload data using `HMAC SHA256` you need a `key`.
This `key` is secret and only known by the server granting you access to its recources.

So this server can generate the JWT token having the header and payload and - using its secret key - generate the verification signature. Then this JWT token is send to you. When you send the JWT token back to the server (because you want to access a resource), the server can check the verification signature using its `key` to check if the signature is valid. If so, it will accept the token, and grand you access.

You probably already feel it comming. Now suppose you generate your own fake JWT token like you describe. You cannot determine the verification signature yourself as you don't have the secret `key`. If you just put any signature, the server will recognise the invalid signature when it verifies it with the true `key` and reject your token.  **That is why you cannot generate your own fake JWT toke that allows you to fake authenticate or impersonate.**

*TLDR:*

One more thing, like others have pointed out. When the server sends you a valid JWT token, it can be stolen! If someone obtains this valid JWT token, than that someone can impersonate you and get access to the resources on your behaf. They cannot change the token or generate their own, but they can use the stolen one as is.

That is why, just like normal passwords, a JWT token should be send over an encrypted communication channel like HTTPS so only you and the server can see the token.

Also, your JWT token should have an expiration time. In case it does get stolen, the attacker has access only for limited time which hopefully reduces the damage.

Hope this clarify things a bit.

Answer (score 2):

> What if I generate token on my side and fill it with data I saw, how the system will distinguish my token from it's own ones?

Sure. If you know the secret the server uses, you can do this. If the secret is not secret anymore, the security model of JWT Tokens are fundamentally broken, and nothing can rescue it.

Typically [HMAC SHA256](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519) is used for authentication:

> JSON Web Token (JWT) is a compact, URL-safe means of representing claims to be transferred between two parties.  The claims in a JWT are encoded as a JSON object that is used as the payload of a JSON Web Signature (JWS) structure or as the plaintext of a JSON Web Encryption (JWE) structure, enabling the claims to be digitally signed or integrity protected with a Message Authentication Code (MAC) and/or encrypted.